# Python code that search for text and copy it to the next line

Tags: python

I python code to read lines in a text file and to copy text between specific characters. For example, text between _ _.

```
Input
./2425/1/115_Lube_45484.jpg 45484
./2425/1/114_Spencerian_73323.jpg 73323

Output
./2425/1/115_Lube_45484.jpg 45484
Lube
./2425/1/114_Spencerian_73323.jpg 73323
Spencerian
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you looked at regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of regex i would use build in: split()

```
input = './2425/1/114_Spencerian_73323.jpg 73323'

output = input.split('_')[1]
print(output)
```

Of course if every line has double _ in input string

Comment: Oops. What is `input.split('_')[1]` then?

Comment: split(' _ ') returns left and right part of string separated by ' _ ' which means:
"./2425/1/114"
and
"Spencerian_73323.jpg 73323"
I choose [1] - second part and split again

Comment: `input.split('_')[1]` gives the desired answer. No need to split again. :)

Comment: you're right, oh my fault :)
corrected

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do not want to print the text, I just want to copy it to the next line. Also, how to read lines in the text file?

Comment: @NiddalImam, there is a gazillion of answers on SO to read from text file. Have you researched yourselves?

Comment: Right, I figure out how to read the file. However, when I run it, I got this error: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

for line in your_text.splitlines():
    result = re.match("_(.*)_", your_text)
    print(match.group(0))
    print(match.group(1))
```

Where `your_text` is a string containing your example as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = './2425/1/114_Spencerian_73323.jpg_abc_ 73323'

result = test.split("_",1)[1].split("_")[0]

print(result)
```

.split('*',1) splits the string in 2 parts i-e: 0 index will be left substring of '*' and 1 index will be right substring of string. We again split the right part of string with '_' so that the text between _ will be extracted.

Note : this will be helpful only when there is single occurence of text between _ like *test*. It wont extract text if there exist this case multiple times in a string

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
file_path = "text_file.txt"

with open(file_path) as f:
    line = f.readline()
    count= 1
    while line:
        print(line,line.split('_')[1])
        line = f.readline()

        count+= 1
```

Thank you all